# Converting area within a polygon of coordinates to metres

Tags: r, gis

given a set of coordinates

```
 lat <- c(47.2325618, 47.2328269, 47.2330041, 47.2330481, 47.2330914, 
          47.2331172, 47.2331291, 47.2331499)
 lon <- c(11.3707441, 11.3707791, 11.3708087, 11.3708031, 11.3707818, 
          11.3707337, 11.3706588, 11.370284)
coords <- cbind(lon,lat)
```

I want to calculate the area of the polygon. I use the function `areapl()` from package *splancs*:

```
library(splancs)
areapl(coords)
# [1] 1.4768e-07
```

this leaves me with a dimension in degrees squared (?). so my question is: **how do i convert this into metres/kilometres?**

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You first have to project that lat/long into metres, and then calculate the area.

Comment: @nograpes Thank you for your answer but honestly: I haven't got the slightest clue how to convert this ;) sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either convert to a cartesian grid system (eg a UTM zone) using `spTransform` in the `sp` package, or try `areaPolygon` in the `geosphere` package.

```
> areaPolygon(coords)
[1] 7688.568
```