# Calculating polygon area with R geosphere package

Tags: r, geospatial, geosphere

I'm having trouble with the areaPolygon function in R.  Sometimes it appears to produce the correct result, and sometimes the results seem orders of magnitude off.

E.g. I have a polygon with these points:

```
lng <- c(-51.74768, -51.74768, -51.74735, -51.74735)
lat <- c(-0.1838690, -0.1840993, -0.1840984, -0.1838682)
```

and combine them into a dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(lng, lat)
```

Then I try to get the area:

```
area <- geosphere::areaPolygon(x = data)
```

which comes out to 326928.8 m^2.

I was expecting something more in the 1000 m^2 range.

What's weird is that this seems to work fairly well for about half the cells I'm calculating, but not the other half.

A [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635761/understanding-the-output-of-areapolygon-from-package-geosphere) noted strangely small values, due to the points being in an incorrect order.  However, when I plot, e.g.

```
plot(data, type="l")
```

The polygon seems to be drawing correctly.

Anyone know what might be wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: I use your code and data and gets [1] 935.2693... It seems ok :)

Comment: So it appears that lats and lngs must be rounded to produce a valid answer.  (The code above has rounded lat/lngs, but my dataset had more digits, and was producing the very large number.) I don't really understand it, but seem to have fixed my problem.

Comment: try to give an example with not-rounded coordinates. perhaps try to use higher-than-7 `options(digits = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

With your example data, result is as expected, as noted in the comments.

```
library(geosphere)
lng <- c(-51.74768, -51.74768, -51.74735, -51.74735)
lat <- c(-0.1838690, -0.1840993, -0.1840984, -0.1838682)
d <- cbind(lng, lat)
geosphere::areaPolygon(d)
#[1] 935.2693
```

The idea that rounding plays a role seems far-fetched.